error: module not found: javafx.controls on ubuntu
I have a problem running Java FX code. I use Ubuntu 22.04.03 and openjdk 17.0.10 .
I downloaded javafx from the link here
Then, according to its documentation, I typed this command in the terminal:
export PATH_TO_FX=Downloads/program/javafx-sdk-22/lib

Now, in another folder where there is HelloFX.java file, I type this command:
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java

But it gives the following error:
error: module not found: javafx.controls
1 error

I searched a lot and all the sites told me to do the same and use it, but I couldn't.

Looks to me that the value assigned to [variable] PATH_TO_FX is a relative path. If so, then I think you need to assign an absolute path rather than a relative path.

@Abra are you sure, that absolute paths are preferred for JavaFX to compile? The getting started documentation doesn't really mention that to be strictly followed anyway.

@Naman I think an absolute path is preferred and a more reliable method of locating the JavaFX SDK libraries, even if the documentation doesn't explicitly say that.

When you use a relative path to define an environment variable or reference a file or directory, the path will be interpreted based on the current location from which the command using it is executed.
For example, if you define an environment variable with a relative path like PATH_TO_FX=../directory, the path will be interpreted based on the current location when the command using this variable is executed.
I believe that the path used in the docs is a placeholder, so it is correct to set an absolute path to the environment variable PATH_TO_FX:
export PATH_TO_FX=/home/<username>/Downloads/program/javafx-sdk-22/lib.
